# Session em Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, session

Em meu controller, faço o login da seguinte maneira:

```
if(!empty($input['user'])) {
            $result = $this->userRepository->searchuser($input['user']); //Busca o usuario pelo login
            // dd($result['data']['user']);

            if ($result['success']) {
                $request->session()->put('user', $result['data']['user']); //Armazeno os dados do usuario numa sessão

                if (Auth::loginUsingId($result['data']['user']->id)) {
                    return redirect('/');//faz o login e redireciona para a rota
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    return view('web::login');
```

E em outro controller eu recupero o valor da session:

```
if($request->session()->has('user')) {
        $user = $request->session()->get('user');
    }        

    return view ('web::profile')->with(compact('user'));
```

O problema é que às vezes o valor é gravado e às vezes não, daí quando recupero o valor na view, ele dá erro por não achar os dados da sessão. Outro problema é que quando funciona e ele consegue recuperar os valores da session, depois que clico em alguma link de uma rota (`<a href="/home"></a>`), a sessão expira.
Algum Jedi em laravel consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a classe do Laravel própria para pegar dados do usuário autenticado.

```
\Auth::user()
```